# UNIX - FTP Using Parameterized Values

Tags: shell, unix, parameters, ftp

I have been stuck in this problem in a few days now and I really need help. My goal is to FTP a certain file into a bridge server. But before I can FTP, I need to enter some login credentials first. I want the login part to be automated that's why I created a separated parameter file. That parameter file has the login details.

So when I run the script, first it will create a txt file. Then the text file will be passed into the bridge server. Now, the script will also pass the login details from the parameter file to access the bridge server and finally a successful FTP. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

FTPFILE="File to be ftped"

Lets say the parameterised file has the details in the format
`HostName username password`.

Read the file contents using a loop statement like or however you like

I am using a while loop here

`while read hostname username password
do
    HOST=${hostname}
    LOGIN=${username}
    PWD=${password}
done`

write the details - hostname,login, password to the $HOME/.netrc file 

    `echo "machine ${HOST} login ${LOGIN} password ${PWD}"  > /$HOME/.netrc
    echo "macdef init"  >> /$HOME/.netrc
    echo "put ${FTPFILE} " >> /$HOME/.netrc
    echo "bye"  >> /$HOME/.netrc
    echo >> /$HOME/.netrc`

[Ftp](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ftp.htm) statement (Ftp first looks for [.netrc](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl5_netrc.htm) file in $HOME directory to initiate the login process. If the file is not found then the username and password will be prompted)
`ftp -i $HOST`

Answer (score 0):

**This code will do the job:**

```
#!/bin/sh

FTP_USERNAME=username
FTP_PASSWORD=password
FTP_SERVER=server_domaine

touch /directory/textfile.txt

run_access_server()
{
              lftp <<STOP
              #automatically access the server
              open -u $FTP_USERNAME,$FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_SERVER
              #changing directory
              cd /directory/on/server
              lcd /from/where/you/fetch/
              #upload the file using get
              mget textfile.txt

        bye
STOP
}

run_access_server
```

Tell me how it works out with you.Regards